# Python Selenium with Google - How to extract images

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webdriver

I am trying to extract all the images from an OfferUp search with selenium, but I've tried a bunch of different codes, and none have worked. I want to be able to show all the images in another website or a pop up so I can have an update on the prices of items on OfferUp.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time


# Driver path
chrome_driver_path = 'C:\\Users\gues\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\PyFiles\\chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()

# Open webpage
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
openOfferUp = driver.get('https://offerup.com/search?q=dresser&DISTANCE=20&DELIVERY_FLAGS=p&PRICE_MAX=100')

#retrieve images
time.sleep(20)
images = driver.find_elements((By.TAG_NAME, 'img'))
image_urls = [image.get_attribute('src') for image in images]
for url in image_urls:
    print(url)

time.sleep(1000)
```

Comment: maybe first check what HTML you get from page - see `openOfferUp.page_source` - because page may block access for `Selenium` or it may send different `HTML` as you expect.

Comment: BTW: when I visit link from your code then I see only `Sorry, we weren’t able to determine your location`. And `OfferUp is only available in the US` but I don't  live in USA so I can't test your code.

Comment: I have been able to maneuver around OfferUp with Selenium, but I think my syntax is wrong.  Whether Selenium has updated it's syntax or I am using it incorrectly.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I was able to fix it with ```images = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'img')
for img in images:
    print(img.get_attribute('src'))```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
images = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'img')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

```
img_urls = [img_element.get_attribute("src") for img_element in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, {img_xpath})]
```